# How to connect mouse to Android phone via ADB?

Tags: adb, scrcpy

I want to play an Android game on my PC but since my phone can play it better, I've hooked it up to my PC using USB with scrcpy and a bluetooth keyboard, however unfortunately, I don't have a bluetooth mouse. I also want to charge my phone with my computer while playing the game.

I use Mantis Mouse Pro to run the game with my keyboard but the scrcpy mouse doesn't appear natively so it can't be mapped. Maybe if possible, I'd even connect my USB PS2 Joystick.

Therefore, I wish to forward the mouse input directly via adb to my phone instead of using scrcpy's Windows mouse. Exactly how you would connect a wi-fi adapter to an Ubuntu VM installed in Windows.

How do I forward mouse input so it appears natively on my phone (with a black cursor)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android is not a VM, there is no USB forwarding protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I figured a way out how to do it with https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/doc%2Fhid-otg.md#physical-mouse-simulation:

- Get scrcpy from your package manager
- Connect adb
- `scrcpy --hid-mouse` or `scrcpy -M`  for short

Answer (score 0):

ADB can't do that. It has no protocol for redirecting USB connections. It can redirect TCP/IP connections, but a USB mouse does not use TCP/IP. A Bluetooth mouse seems to be your easiest solution.